# wwdr.pem not opening in ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, passbook, wallet, passkit

I created `apple wallet pass` in `IOS` successfully but when i moved these files in my `ubuntu` system it is showing following error.

> Error: Error opening certificate file /key/wwdr.pem
>   140164248454816:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:175:fopen('/key/wwdr.pem','r')
>   140164248454816:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:182:

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks pretty self explanatory - you application can't find the `wwdr.pem` file check your paths, and where your application believes root to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i saved pem file with capitals in Mac it worked in Mac but in Ubuntu i had to save same file with smalls.Than it worked.